# Deploy vs Invoke in programming context

Tags: word-choice, difference, verbs

I frequently saw words ‘invoke’ and ‘deploy’ used in meaning of “to use something that resolve problem of certain domain” in software technology blog posts. What are differences between them and when should I select which one?

Comment: Please look the words up in a dictionary, and then tell us if there is something you still don't understand.

Comment: No doubt it depends on the *specific* context, and this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607263/what-happened-exactly-on-chaincode-deploy-and-invoke-query-in-hyperledger) defines them in relation to a particular software tool called Chaincode. I haven't heard the term *deploy* used before, in the context of programming, other than its usual meaning in English, for example "It is time to deploy the debugger."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the obscure domain-specific use of two words

Comment: I'm voting to close also, because these words have very specific meanings depending on your toolset and your programming language. There is no general answer that would make any sense.

Comment: They are terms very pervasive in programming, and I’ve been always searching for dictionary first, but it said the word ‘Invoke’ is “use law to achieve something” or “call something or someone for help, especially god” and thet was absolutely not enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in a programming and software context, the primary difference is that deploying something implies a permanent change in how something will function.

You might invoke commands or functions but you will deploy code or "changes"

Deploying implies greater effort and uniqueness.  You might invoke hundreds of commands a day and your code might invoke thousands of functions a second, but you would only deploy code or a tool a few times a day.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate you very much.